# TextView is not moving back to original position after being scrolled up by keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

EDIT: Adding in viewDidLoad code

So i had done some research to learn how to move one of my text views so that when the keyboard popped up, it scrolled the view up so that the keyboard was not covering the textview. I have seemed to be able to get that work, but now my issue is that after dismissing the keyboard, the view stays where it was. It does not 'snap' back to its original it was in position prior to the keyboard popping up and scrolling the textview out of the way. Am i missing something in my code? Or do i need to add something?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.questionInput.delegate = self
    self.answerInput.delegate = self
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: "DismissKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidShow:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}


var activeView: UITextView?


func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {

    self.activeView = nil
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {

    self.activeView = textView
}

func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let activeView = self.answerInput, keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        var aRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.size.height
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeView.frame.origin)) {
            self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeView.frame, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

My second question was i had read about needing to unregister for keyboard notifications this was the exact quote..

"Do not forget to unregister from these events when you are transitioning away from your view controller."

What exactly does this mean? Does code needed to be added when segueing?

Any help is appreciated as i am quite stuck with both these questions. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: Yes, Sana. I am using autolayout

Comment: I see `self.activeView` and `self.answerInput`.. What's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in the inital stage of the development you can use this library which will take care of keyboard handling throughout your project

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

regarding your second question here is the sample code that you'll need to implement

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}

deinit {
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self);
}
```

If you use autolayout you need to implement this instead

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height + 20
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, mihir. i actually forgot to add in my viewDidLoad code where i did add observer to the notification center already. I am using autolayout though, so should i just add your second example to my code i have now and remove my NSNotificationCenter code from viewDidLoad?

Comment: Great, thank you. and i was just on Github checking out IQKeyboardManager, it looks really awesome! Does using that mean i dont need the code i posted anymore? Since from what i saw on the readme is you dont need to use a scrollview anymore. This would get rid of a lot of headaches for me.

Comment: Yes , it will work without any code , just need to enable it in app delegate and you're done for entire application ...

Comment: Great! this will cut down on a good bit of code for me. I just added it into my project, but when i added the code to enable it in app delegate it is saying use of unresolved identifier IQKeyboardManager. Did i not import correctly?

Comment: You need to import it ... import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

Comment: That is what i figured to try, but then it is telling me no such module.

Comment: it's working fine for me ... check your pod file ... is it correct ... does it have use framework! ?

Comment: i did not use a cocoapod, i tried using the sourcecode method listed on the Github page. Downloaded the demo project and drag and dropped the IQKeyboardManagerSwift directory into my project. Then just enabling in in Appdelegate

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.scrollView.contentInset.top, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)

            self.scrollView.contentInset = insets
            self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sana. Just tried it, but still once the keyboard slides the textview up the textviews dont go back to position after dismissing the keyboard. i will make an edit of what my viewDidLoad looks like if it will help at all